# LXC - Linux Containers - Add new network interface without restarting

Tags: lxc

Searching on google, there's only way to add new network interface is adding to config file. Is there any lxc command that we can add lively, (don't need to restart the container)?

The page mentioned how to add second network interface: http://box.matto.nl/lxctwonics.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It would very much depend on the configuration of the interface you're trying to add to the container.

If you have an existing interface on your host which you want to be visible inside the container:

```
# on the host:
pid=$(lxc-info -pHn foobar)
ip link set dev eth3 netns $pid name eth1
```

This will cause your host's `eth3` interface to be moved to the container `foobar`, renamed to `eth1`. This is roughly equal to this configuration:

```
lxc.network.type=phys
lxc.network.link=eth3
lxc.network.name=eth1
```

---

Another useful scenario would be to create a new interface inside the container, bridged to an existing bridge on the host:

```
# on the host:
pid=$(lxc-info -pHn foobar)
ip link add name veth0 type veth peer name veth0_container
brctl addif br0 veth0
ip link set dev veth0_container netns $pid name veth0
```

This will create a pair of connected virtual-ethernet interfaces (`veth0` and `veth0_container`), add one of them to the `br0` bridge, and move the other into the container `foobar`. This is roughly equivalent to this configuration:

```
lxc.network.type=veth
lxc.network.link=br0
lxc.network.name=veth0
```

Comment: Tks for your answer! How's about adding the IP address for creating a new interface inside the container (your 2nd case): lxc.network.ipv4  = 192.168.1.100/24, lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 192.168.1.1

Comment: BTW, the command should be "ip link add name veth0 type veth peer name veth0_container". And on debian, I can't find lxc-device command

Comment: Oops, added the missing `add` to the `ip link add...` command. I've also updated the answer to avoid the `lxc-device` command, hopefully you have `lxc-info` at least :)

Comment: You should configure the new interface inside the container using your hosted distribution's facilities (e.g. `/etc/network/interfaces` and `ifup`)

Comment: @lanzz Now, how to bring back the devices that is attached to the container as 'phys' back to the host?  without shutting down the container.

Comment: @Viswesn answer doesn't seem obvious after a cursory search, and I don't have much time to check it out; best bet would be to post a separate question about that

Answer (score 1):

Thread very helpful, but I had to set the created link up to make container access to the network:

Before:(ip link)

```
11: veth0@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop master vmbr0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:f1:f9:5a:5c:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
```

Set the link up:

```
ip link set dev veth0 up
```

After:(ip link)

```
11: veth0@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master vmbr0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:f1:f9:5a:5c:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Leahkim I also had to UP the device, but furthermore assign a static IP from within the container:

```
ifconfig veth0 add 192.168.18.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

You could probably use a dhcp client at this point as well, but this wasnt available for me.